# MySQL automatic update for specific column instead of whole record

Tags: mysql, timestamp, auto-update

I have a table APPLEVARIETY. 
It has the following columns:

- id
- family
- color
- description (TEXT)
- description_last_update_time (TIMESTAMP)

For the latter column I would like to use 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. However, this will cause the timestamp to be updated if **at least one of the other columns** are updated (id, family, color).

Instead I would like to specify that the description_last_update_time will get the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if **only the description column** is updated. It should ignore updates on the rest of the columns.

I have looked through the MySQL manual, other questions on stackoverflow and of course used google extensively but found nothing.

So in other words: is there some way to **specify a certain column** with ON UPDATE? Is it even possible or am I moving in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No thats not possible using the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` this will get updated when any column is updated.
You may however achieve the same using a trigger. For that you will first need to remove `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` from the table definition.
The trigger will look like

```
delimiter //

create trigger APPLEVARIETY_update before update on APPLEVARIETY
for each row 
begin
  if new.description <> old.description then
    set new.description_last_update_time = now();
  end if;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. The only remaining problem is, that on the **first update** of the description field the description_last_update_time is not updated to now(). Only from the **second time** I update the description field the description_last_update_time has changed.

Comment: Well I suppose when you first add a record into the table ? In that case I would suggest to add the timestamp value also in the insert command.

Comment: No, the record was already added to the table. Then I used UPDATE it for the first time and the description_last_update_time did not change, it remained 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Maybe I did something wrong with the default value?