# Mysql update trigger except for specific column updates

Tags: mysql, triggers

In MySQL, I want to fire a trigger when update on all columns except one column update.

In my table row I have 40 columns. I want trigger to update the column `update_time` whenever there is an update happens on any field except `update_time` field.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `UpdateDateTrigger`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW 
    IF NOT UPDATE(`update_time`) BEGIN
        SET new.update_timestamp = now()
    END
```

But it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at [MySQL automatic update for specific column instead of whole record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409521/mysql-automatic-update-for-specific-column-instead-of-whole-record/29409605#29409605) , I've got the solution to exclude two columns update in trigger

```
IF !((NEW.last_visited <> OLD.last_visited) || 
(NEW.update_time <> OLD.update_time)) THEN
   SET new.update_time = now();
END IF
```

Thank you!

Comment: It is important to note that in this example if `last_visited` was updated at the same time as another column in the table, the `update_time` would not be updated. Thank you for this solution, it worked great for my situation!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a trigger function I would like to suggest you to create the table wisely so that the update_time field gets updated automatically when something is changed associated with that row.

Please look into the [documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) for automatic update on time for each update of the row. The create syntax is simple and effective.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  // .... Other columns
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

If you want a specific control over each of your column, then writing a trigger is the best idea I think. Please [check the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29409605/3145960) here.

Comment: And I have one column `last_visited`. I don't want to update `update_time` column when last_visited updated. Is there any way we can exclude for one column update. I don't think it is possible with the above solution.

Comment: Oh I see. If you want a specific control over each of your column, then writing a trigger is the best idea I think.

Comment: Please see the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29409605/3145960