# Explaining mysql timestamps of specific row

Tags: mysql

I want to add at row "jailtime" timestamp.  That timestamp would be the timestamp of when "pjailed" row was updated.

I tried to do the fallowing:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45470/get-the-time-of-last-update-of-a-column

But instead of creating table, I wanted to alter existing table, so I went for

```
ALTER TABLE `users` 
CHANGE `jailtime` `jailtime` TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL 
DEFAULT 'updated_at pJailed';
```

But it gives me error "Invalid value for pJailed"

Comment: That's a string value which is not a timestamp so it can't be used because it's not a valid value, just as the error says.

Comment: I have removed PHP tag, as it is not connected to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value for `pJailed` for a row is updated that whole row receives an update. So it would suffice to use `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (and `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) on `jailtime`.

You can alter the column `jailtime` to reflect this using:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
 MODIFY COLUMN jailtime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

---

**Edit:** OP mentioned in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411097/explaining-mysql-timestamps-of-specific-row/52411327#comment91766442_52411327) that the attribute `jailtime` should only be updated when the attribute `pJailed` is updated. To accomplish this one should use a trigger as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29409605/5914775).

Comment: I tried it, and works fine.  But, I updated the "Username" row too and the "jailtime" row modified with the time of "username"'s modification time. I would like that jailtime to be stuck to only pJailed.   pJailed is an INT type and I can't add "Invalid ON UPDATE clause for 'pJailed' column"

Comment: @AlxTioltisan you will need to use a trigger to accomplish that. Please check [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29409605/5914775) for more information.